# Преобразование интерполяции

Tags: javascript

```js
let age =  '19';
let weight = '63';

let str = Number(age);
let str2 = Number(weight);


let result = `${str+ `${str2}`}`;  // По идеи должно выходить число 82, 
                                  //  но вместо этого числа выходит 1963. 
                                 //   Я неправильно преобразовал? Где ошибка(?

alert(result);
```

Comment: мне больше интересно другое, причём тут интерполяция? Если у вас простое сложение двух чисел :|

Comment: что значит словосочетание «преобразование интерполяции»?

Comment: @MoloF  для чего он число делает строкой ?

Comment: @MaximLensky для чего он получает результат сложения двух чисел в виде строки?

Comment: @MoloF не знаю, что ему в голову взбрело

Comment: @MaximLensky но по итогу это называется 'интерполяция' xD

Comment: @MoloF  это лишнии движения называется

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В этом выражении складываются число и строка:

```
str + `${str2}`
```

```js
let age =  '19';
let weight = '63';

let str = Number(age);
let str2 = Number(weight);

let result = `${str + str2}`; // or result = str + str2;
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Получается я не правильно оформил многоуровневую интерполяцию?
В моем случае достаточно одного уровня?

Comment: @Black_Viper Да, Вы неправильно оформили.

Comment: А я правильно преобразовал?

Comment: @Black_Viper я в сотый раз спрашиваю - для чего число оборачивать кавычками что бы потом превратить его в число ?

Comment: @MaximLensky прикола ради)